# MediaRecorder doesn't start in android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, video, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an app where i can upload videos of upto 2 mins per user.
I want the user to record a video and upload it to the server.I am able to do it with intent but not with media recorder.

The requirement is to not allow user to preview the video and instead record it and when user stops recording, upload the video to server.
(Is it possible to not allow the playback of the recorded video in VIDEO_CAPTURE intent ???)

I am trying to record a video with media recorder. But it throws an exception at MediaRecorder.Start()

Here's the code : -

```
//Class level variables
    Camera  PhoneCamera;
    VideoView VideoRecorderView;
    MediaRecorder VideoRecorder;
    Button BtnRecordVideo;

    // I start a video recording on click of the button
    void RecordVideoWithCustomRecorder(object sender,EventArgs e){
                //TODO : Create a custom layout for recording video in one shot and then uplaoding it to kaltura server
                if (IsRecording) {
                    VideoRecorder.Stop ();
                    ReleaseMediaRecorder ();
                    PhoneCamera.Lock ();
                    (sender as Button).SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.record_red);
                    StopTimer ();
                    //UploadVideo
                    byte[] getBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (RecorderFile._file.AbsolutePath);
                    UploadVideoToKaltura (getBytes);

                    IsRecording = false;

                } else {
                    ReleaseCamera ();
                    if (PrepareVideoRecorder ()) {
                        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (1000); i tried putting this, but it won't work

                        VideoRecorder.Start ();//I get an exception here - not sure why
                        RunOnUiThread (() => {
                            (sender as Button).SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.record_stop);
                            initTimer2 ();
                            IsRecording = true;
                        });

                    } else {
                        ReleaseMediaRecorder ();
                        RunOnUiThread (() => {
                            AlertDialogManager.ShowDialogWithSingleButton(this,"Video Error","Can't record the video now. Exit the camera and try recording again.","Exit Camera",(()=>{
                                this.Finish();
                            }));
                        });
                    }

                }


            }


    //Here's the code to prepare the media recorder

    bool PrepareVideoRecorder(){

                PhoneCamera = IsFrontCameraAvailable ? Camera.Open (1) : Camera.Open ();
                VideoRecorder = new MediaRecorder ();

                //Unlock & set camera to media recorder
                PhoneCamera.Unlock ();
                VideoRecorder.SetCamera (PhoneCamera);

                //Set Source - Video and audio
                VideoRecorder.SetAudioSource (AudioSource.Camcorder);
                VideoRecorder.SetVideoSource (VideoSource.Camera);

                //set Camcorder profile
                VideoRecorder.SetProfile(CamcorderProfile.Get(CamcorderQuality.High));

                //set output file
                RecorderFile._file = new File(RecorderFile._dir, String.Format("vm_movie_{0}.mp4", Guid.NewGuid()));
                VideoRecorder.SetOutputFile (RecorderFile._file.AbsolutePath);

                //set preview display
                VideoRecorder.SetPreviewDisplay (VideoRecorderView.Holder.Surface);

                //Prepare media recorder
                VideoRecorder.SetMaxDuration (12000);
                try{
                    VideoRecorder.Prepare();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Utils.WriteDebugInfo ("Excepion -PrepareVideoRecorder: " + ex.Message);
                    return false;

                }
                return true;
            }

            //Release Media Recorder
            private void ReleaseMediaRecorder(){
                if (VideoRecorder != null) {
                    VideoRecorder.Reset();   // clear recorder configuration
                    VideoRecorder.Release(); // release the recorder object
                    VideoRecorder = null;
                    PhoneCamera.Lock();           // lock camera for later use
                }
            }

            //Release Camers
            private void ReleaseCamera(){
                if (PhoneCamera != null){
                    PhoneCamera.Release ();
                          // release the camera for other applications
                    PhoneCamera = null;
                }
            }


            //Creating app specific diary for videos
            private void CreateDirectoryForVideos()
            {
                RecorderFile._dir = new File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures),"VirtualMentorVideos");
                if (!RecorderFile._dir.Exists())
                {
                    RecorderFile._dir.Mkdirs();
                }
            }
```